# LIN is synchronous or asynchronous protocol?

Tags: embedded

From datasheet Local Interconnect Network (LIN) is the synchronous communication protocol, but we are not sending any data along with the clock, both master and slave are having their own internal clock. Then how it will be treated as synchronous communication.

In SPI, data and clock are sent to slave using separate pin.

In UART, only TX and RX is used. (baud rate is set in both sides no common clock).

Comment: Stop mixing physical and data layers and you will answer this question by your own.

Comment: This would be a better question if you could tell us what you think synchronous and asynchronous means.

Comment: Better citation required - what datasheet? What section of that datasheet?  Provide a link - for context.

Answer (score 2):

At the LIN [data protocol layer](https://microchipdeveloper.com/lin:protocol-overview) a transaction comprises of the master sending a header and a slave sending a *response*.  That interaction is *synchronous*.

It is not the same sense as a [*synchronous serial communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_serial_communication) which is a *physical layer* attribute.  Same word, different context - different protocol stack layer.